# $1+ 2^{\alpha} + 3^{\alpha} + \dots + n^{\alpha} = \Theta(n^{\alpha+1})$ for all real $\alpha > 0$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I know the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ but couldn't find a generalization for real powers, is there a generalization to help prove this or some other way?

Comment: $$\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}=\int_0^n x^\alpha dx\le 1^\alpha+\dots+n^\alpha\le \int_1^{n+1}x^{\alpha}dx=\frac{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}-1}{\alpha+1}$$

Comment: What is $\Omega(n^{\alpha+1})$? is it perhaps $O(n^{\alpha+1})$?

Comment: For $\alpha>0$, $1+2^\alpha+\ldots n^{\alpha}\leq nn^{\alpha}=n^{1+\alpha}$

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks, can you link to the theorem that gives these bounds? seems like Riemann sums but couldn't find the exact theorem

Comment: @OliverDiaz $f(n) = \Omega(g(n)) \iff g(n) = O(f(n))$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your goal is to find an asymptotic estimate of a sum, you don't need to find a formula and you shouldn't look for one. It is rare that (as with the $\alpha \in \mathbb N$ case here) we can find a closed form for the sum exactly. Asymptotic analysis is about upper and lower bounds.

Here, the easiest upper bound is
$$
   1^\alpha + 2^\alpha + \dots + n^\alpha \le \underbrace{n^\alpha + n^\alpha + \dots + n^\alpha}_{n \text{ times}} = n^{\alpha+1}.
$$
This is all we need.

For the lower bound, consider that the last $\frac n2$ terms are all at least $(\frac n2)^\alpha$. Replace the first $\frac n2$ terms by $0$, the last $\frac n2$ terms by $(\frac n2)^\alpha$, and simplify; you should get a lower bound that's $n^{\alpha+1}$ times a constant only depending on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R^+$ is an increasing function, then
$$
\int_0^n f(x)\,dx\le f(1)+f(2)+\dots+f(n)\le \int_1^{n+1}f(x)\,dx
$$
The first inequality follows from upper bounding $\int_0^n f(x)\,dx$ with a right-endpoint Riemann sum, and the second follows from using a left-endpoint Riemann sum on $\int_1^{n+1}f(x)\,dx$. These are lower/upper bounds because for any $x\in [k,k+1]$, we have $f(k)\le f(x)\le f(k+1)$.